# Attempting to create sandbox account fails every time

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create a sandbox account one of each type (business and personal) but no matter what I enter or do it fails every time and gives a vague message saying it there was an error. Is this normal? Do I have to provision something first? The documentation doesn't help much if things don't go as expected.

Comment: You're not alone - creating and fetching previously created apps/sandbox accounts is broken in dashboard. Testing with those accounts however seems to still work - so hopefully it's just a UI thing...

Comment: Can you create a sandbox account from the command line or something?

Comment: Things seem to be back up now - dashboard displays all previously created apps, sandbox accounts :)

Answer (score -1):

Where did you create the account? I created my sandbox accounts in the PayPal developers page (https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2F)

Comment: Dashboard is _currently broken_ - creating or viewing previously setup apps/accts.